# Counter-example: If $U \subseteq X$ is open and we have a S.E.S of Abelian sheaves, the corresponding S.E.S of rings/modules may not be exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm looking for a counter-example for the problem in title when $F_1$ is not flabby. We know that if $0\to F_1 \to F_2 \to F_3\to 0$ is a short exact sequence of Abelian sheaves and $F_1$ is flabby then for any $U \subseteq X$ which is open we have the following exact sequence:
$$0\to F_1(U) \to F_2(U) \to F_3(U)\to 0$$

Is there a counter-example that shows this may no longer be true if $F_1$ is not flabby? If yes, how a counter-example can be constructed?

**Edit:** I'm looking for a solution without reference to manifolds or De Rham cohomology. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: You need $H^1(U,F_3)$ to not vanish, so you should look on something non-affine. What's the simplest such object? Try constructing examples there with $F_1(X)=F_2(X)=0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey  Thanks for the link. I'm looking for a solution without assuming De Rham Cohomology or knowledge of manifolds.

Comment: @KReiser  I haven't studied cohomology yet. This question belongs to chapter 4, while cohomology is covered in chapter 8 and 9. However, i know a little bit of homological algebra from my Algebraic Topology course. So, if that suffices, would you please expand your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most classical exact sequences in sheaves is the exponential
sequence. This is
$$0\to \Bbb Z\stackrel{\times 2\pi i}{\to}\Bbb C\stackrel
{\exp}\to\Bbb C^*\to0$$
where $\Bbb C$ here denotes the sheaf whose sections on $U$ are the continuous
maps from $U$ to $\Bbb C$ etc. This is generally not exact on sections.
If say $X=\Bbb C^*$ there is no continuous map from $\Bbb C^*$ to $\Bbb C$
whose exponential is the identity map. Of course $\Bbb Z$ (as a sheaf)
won't be flabby in general.

Comment: Would you please add the sheaf structures in your answer too? How is $\mathbb{Z}$ viewed as a sheaf? Thanks.

Comment: In exactly the same way: continuous maps to $\Bbb Z$ (which is discrete).

Comment: Interesting. And one more question before I'm fully convinced, why is that a short exact sequence of Abelian sheaves? In other words, why is $\mathbb{C}^*$ the smallest subsheaf containing $\mathrm{pre}-\exp(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Every continuous nonzero function is **locally** an exponential of a continuous function.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful solution.